# how to access document files from firebase and show them in gridview?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter and i want to develop app that access all pdf files from my firebase directory and show them in grid view in my flutter app any help can be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a StreamBuilder widget. Set the stream arg as the query for how you want to receive the data and then use builder.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collection-name").snapshots(),
    builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
            // Use streamSnapshot and widgets of your choice
        }
);
```

Check the docs for specifics: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html